# C program stopped working after use scanf

Tags: c, codeblocks

so i have this C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   scanf("%d", &b);
   scanf("%d", &a);
   c = a + b;
   printf(c);
   return 0;
}
```

but, after i insert number for a and b, the program stop working. please help me
C noob here

Comment: You know the syntax of `printf()`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have the following line is wrong:

```
printf(c);
```

as the **printf()** syntax would be like what i've written below

```
printf("%d",c);
```

so your now code would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   scanf("%d", &b);
   scanf("%d", &a);
   c= a + b;
   printf("%d",c); //this is the correct printf() syntax 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And why is  that? C *ignores* whitespace.

Comment: Add the whitespace back. Your code looks much cramped when compared to the OP's as you removed the whitespace.

Comment: For this program, no. It isn't.

Comment: thanks! i thought printf() function works like print() in python XD

Answer (score 0):

```
printf(c);
```

should be

```
printf("%d\n", c); /* `\n` at the end of the string flushes the `stdout` */
```

because `printf` expects a `const char*` as its first argument, not an `int`.

Comment: Don't forget that `scanf` might leave some newlines in and won't scan the next integer, resulting in trying to add a non-null `int` and a null value together.

Comment: But `%d` won't scan a newline character. The only format specifiers for which whitespace is relevant are `%c`, `%[` and `%n`. Try the program.